# Check if networkfile exists

Tags: raspbian

I've Googled a lot but I can't fix this.

For local files I get it to work, but for a networkfile it doesn't.

I want to check if a file *on a network* exists, but how?

I tried this in my terminal:

```
 [ -f "192.168.1.46:8090/camera.jpg" ] && echo 1 || echo 0
```

It outputs constantly 0, while I'm sure the file exists, can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

To be more clear:

On my Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian), I run FFserver and FFmpeg. It transcode a stream to camera.mjpeg and camera.jpg. The local IP address of my Raspberry Pi itself is 19.168.1.46, so I want to check if file is still there, because sometimes the transcoding process hangs, and the mjpeg is unreadable. I have this shell code now:

```
  #!/bin/bash       
  url=http://192.168.1.46:80/test.txt
  url2=http://192.168.1.46:8090/camera.mjpeg

  if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url"; then
    echo "URL exists: $url"
  else
    echo "URL does not exist: $url"
  fi

  if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url2"; then
    echo "URL exists: $url2"
  else
    echo "URL does not exist: $url2"
  fi
```

This is the output:

```
  URL exists: http://192.168.1.46:80/test.txt
  URL does not exist: http://192.168.1.46:8090/camera.mjpeg
```

The problem is: I know for sure the camera.mjpeg is there, because I can access it via a browser on another PC and view it without problems, but it still says that it doesm't exsists.

Comment: What's being served on 192.168.1.46:8090? HTTP? FTP? NFS? Gopher?

Comment: Use `wget` or `curl` and check the return code.

Comment: How does the computer know that `192.168.1.46:8090` is not a directory specification? ( the `:` is allowed in a file-name).

Answer (score -1):

`192.168.1.46:8090/camera.jpg` is just the name of a non-existent file (a file named `camera.jpg` in a *local* directory named `./192.168.1.46:8090`. Directory `./192.168.1.46:8090` does not exist).

You will need to use a program that can access the server, such as curl or wget.

If the server is HTTP, then use `curl` option `--head` to tell the server to not send the file, but only send the HTTP header. This should be enough. e.g. `curl --head http://192.168.1.46:8090/camera.jpg`

Comment: If i use `curl --head 192.168.1.46:8090/camera.jpg`

I get:

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server` Wat does "Empty reply" mean?

Comment: What protocol is the server running?

Comment: My server runs HTTP

Comment: I have no idea. What happens when you try to fetch the file (without `--head`, or with a web browser).